# Specify not to match something in regex

Tags: c#, regex

My input has nested parenthesis with similar nodes within nodes. Sample data:

```
(S (S (NP (PRP It)) (VP (VP (VBZ has) (VP (VBN been) (PP (IN over) (NP (NN half))) (NP (DT a) (NN year)) (SBAR (IN since) (S (NP (DT a) (ADJP (CD 19.5) (NN %)) (NN tax)) (VP (VBD was) (VP (VBN imposed) (PP (IN by) (NP (NP (NN government)) (PP (IN of) (NP (NNP Punjab))))) (PP (IN on) (NP (DT the) (NN internet) (NNS services))))))))) (CC and) (VP (ADVP (RB just)) (VBP like) (NP (JJ YouTube) (NN ban)) (PRT (RP back)) (PP (IN in) (NP (CD 2012)))))) (, ,) (NP (NP (DT this) (NN internet) (NN tax)) (PP (IN in) (NP (NP (DT the) (JJS largest) (NN province)) (PP (IN of) (NP (NNP Pakistan)))))) (VP (VBZ does) (RB n't) (VP (VB seem) (S (VP (TO to) (VP (VB see) (NP (PRP$ its) (NN end)) (PP (ADVP (NP (DT any) (NN time)) (RB soon)) (IN despite) (NP (NP (JJ various) (JJ verbal) (NN commitment)) (PP (IN by) (NP (JJ Chief) (NNP Minister) (NNP Shahbaz) (NNP Sharif) (CC and) (JJ Provincial) (NN Finance) (NNP Minister) (NNP Ayesha) (NNPS Ghaus) (NNP Pasha))))) (PP (IN with) (NP (PDT all) (DT the) (NNS stakeholders)))))))) (. .))
(S (NP (JJ Inside) (NNS reports)) (VP (VBD confirmed) (SBAR (IN that) (S (NP (NP (DT a) (NN camp) (NN lead)) (PP (IN by) (NP (NP (NNP Chairman) (NNP Punjab) (NNP Revenue) (NNP Authority)) (PRN (-LRB- -LRB-) (NP (NNP PRA)) (-RRB- -RRB-))))) (VP (VBZ is) (NP (DT no) (NN mood) (S (VP (TO to) (VP (VB revoke) (NP (DT the) (NN tax)) (SBAR (IN that) (S (NP (PRP it)) (VP (VBD implemented) (PP (IN on) (NP (NNP May) (CD 28) (, ,) (CD 2014)))))))))))))) (. .))
(S (PP (IN On) (NP (DT the) (JJ other) (NN hand))) (, ,) (NP (NP (NNS people)) (PP (IN like) (NP (NP (NNP Chairman) (NNP PITB)) (, ,) (NP (NNP Umar) (NNP Saif)) (, ,)))) (VP (VBZ has) (VP (VBN been) (VP (VBG speaking) (PP (IN against) (NP (JJ such) (JJ anti-technology) (NN tax)))))) (. .))
(S (PP (IN In) (NP (PRP$ his) (JJ various) (NN statement))) (, ,) (NP (PRP he)) (VP (VBZ has) (VP (VBN shown) (NP (NN hope)) (SBAR (IN that) (S (NP (NNS things)) (VP (MD would) (VP (VB get) (NP (QP (JJR better) (IN but) (DT no)) (NNS signs)) (ADVP (RB yet)))))))) (. .))
```

I am interested in matching VP nodes, which happen to have multiple other VP nodes inside. So I want to match the last VP node. My regex:

```
\(VP\s*((?!VP)|[^()]+|(?<Level>\()|(?<-Level>\)))+(?(Level)(?!))\)
```

The output is as follows:

```
(VP (VP (VBZ has) (VP (VBN been) (PP (IN over) (NP (NN half))) (NP (DT a) (NN year)) (SBAR (IN since) (S (NP (DT a) (ADJP (CD 19.5) (NN %)) (NN tax)) (VP (VBD was) (VP (VBN imposed) (PP (IN by) (NP (NP (NN government)) (PP (IN of) (NP (NNP Punjab))))) (PP (IN on) (NP (DT the) (NN internet) (NNS services))))))))) (CC and) (VP (ADVP (RB just)) (VBP like) (NP (JJ YouTube) (NN ban)) (PRT (RP back)) (PP (IN in) (NP (CD 2012)))))
(VP (VBZ does) (RB n't) (VP (VB seem) (S (VP (TO to) (VP (VB see) (NP (PRP$ its) (NN end)) (PP (ADVP (NP (DT any) (NN time)) (RB soon)) (IN despite) (NP (NP (JJ various) (JJ verbal) (NN commitment)) (PP (IN by) (NP (JJ Chief) (NNP Minister) (NNP Shahbaz) (NNP Sharif) (CC and) (JJ Provincial) (NN Finance) (NNP Minister) (NNP Ayesha) (NNPS Ghaus) (NNP Pasha))))) (PP (IN with) (NP (PDT all) (DT the) (NNS stakeholders))))))))
(VP (VBD confirmed) (SBAR (IN that) (S (NP (NP (DT a) (NN camp) (NN lead)) (PP (IN by) (NP (NP (NNP Chairman) (NNP Punjab) (NNP Revenue) (NNP Authority)) (PRN (-LRB- -LRB-) (NP (NNP PRA)) (-RRB- -RRB-))))) (VP (VBZ is) (NP (DT no) (NN mood) (S (VP (TO to) (VP (VB revoke) (NP (DT the) (NN tax)) (SBAR (IN that) (S (NP (PRP it)) (VP (VBD implemented) (PP (IN on) (NP (NNP May) (CD 28) (, ,) (CD 2014))))))))))))))
(VP (VBZ has) (VP (VBN been) (VP (VBG speaking) (PP (IN against) (NP (JJ such) (JJ anti-technology) (NN tax))))))
(VP (VBZ has) (VP (VBN shown) (NP (NN hope)) (SBAR (IN that) (S (NP (NNS things)) (VP (MD would) (VP (VB get) (NP (QP (JJR better) (IN but) (DT no)) (NNS signs)) (ADVP (RB yet))))))))
```

What I want to match, for example, in line 1 I would like to match only the inner most VP:

```
(VP (VBN been) (PP (IN over) (NP (NN half))) (NP (DT a) (NN year)) (SBAR (IN since) (S (NP (DT a) (ADJP (CD 19.5) (NN %)) (NN tax)) (VP (VBD was) (VP (VBN imposed) (PP (IN by) (NP (NP (NN government)) (PP (IN of) (NP (NNP Punjab))))) (PP (IN on) (NP (DT the) (NN internet) (NNS services))))))))) (CC and) (VP (ADVP (RB just)) (VBP like) (NP (JJ YouTube) (NN ban)) (PRT (RP back)) (PP (IN in) (NP (CD 2012)))
```

Hence to ignore two levels `(VP (VP (VBZ has)`.
Any idea how can I specify a negative match group withing nested bracket matching?

Comment: I don't think that regular expressions are the right tool here for parsing recursive structures. Looks like a Lisp dialect, maybe you have more luck by looking for or writing a Lisp parser/evaluator instead?

Comment: If you just need to avoid matching substrings starting with `(VP (VP...` enclose your pattern with a capturing group (remove the lookahead only alternative), and prepend the pattern with `\(VP\s+\(VP\b|`, and grab only the capturing group 1  values. Also, your expected value contains an unbalanced number of `()`.

Comment: [Here is what I mean](http://ideone.com/D1XjMV).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to find the last instance of `VP` as your starting point.  The rest of your regex can ignore whether it contains `VP`.

```
\(VP\s+(?!.*\(VP\s)([^()]+|(?<Level>\()|(?<-Level>\)))+(?(Level)(?!))\)


\(VP\s+          # Look for "(VP "
(?!.*\(VP\s)     # Must not be followed by "(VP "
([^()]+|(?<Level>\()|(?<-Level>\)))+(?(Level)(?!))    # Arbitrary nested content
\)               # Closing parenthesis for "(VP ..."
```